# How to add method comments with Live template in IntelliJ idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javadoc

I would like to generate comments automatically,but the /**+enter only generates Javadoc containing the @param and @return tags.

I want to also generate the date and author,but when I made the Live Template, I used methodparameters() to autogenerate parameters, but this does not work outside of the method. I had to generate documentation in the method and then move the it to the top of the method.

How do I generate comments outside of a method with the @param,@author,and @date tags?

**Update**:

@javau's answer worked out,tanks! Thanks for fixing grammar,Luciano van der Veekens

I modified the xml like that:

```html
<template name="auth" value="@author $USER$ &#10;    * @since  $DATE;" description="Inset Javadoc @author and @since tags" toReformat="true" toShortenFQNames="true">
  <variable name="USER" expression="user()" defaultValue="" alwaysStopAt="false" />
  <variable name="DATE" expression="date()" defaultValue="" alwaysStopAt="false" />
  <context>
    <option name="JAVA_COMMENT" value="true" />
  </context>
</template>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You won't be able to do exactly what you want. The `/**`<kbd>Enter</kbd> shortcut isn't a live template per se. And it can't be edited. And a live template does not have access to the method parameters of a method it is not inside of.

Long term, I recommend you [open a feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA) that a setting be put in to include the `@author` and `@since` tags when the `/**` shortcut is used.

For now, you can do it in two steps. Create a live template to insert the `@author` and `@since` tags. (I have an example below you can copy and paste.) Then you would need to type: `/**`<kbd>Enter</kbd>`auth`<kbd>Tab</kbd> where `auth` is the shortcut for your live template. You would end up with something like:

```
/**
 * @author Dilbert
 * @since 2017-06-07
 * @param foo
 * @param bar
 */
void m1(String foo, String bar)
```

Here's an example template:

```
<template name="auth" value="@author $USER$ &#10;    * @since  $DATE$&#10;    *" description="Inset Javadoc @author and @since tags" toReformat="true" toShortenFQNames="true">
  <variable name="USER" expression="user()" defaultValue="" alwaysStopAt="false" />
  <variable name="DATE" expression="date()" defaultValue="" alwaysStopAt="false" />
  <context>
    <option name="JAVA_COMMENT" value="true" />
  </context>
</template>
```

**UPDATE**

To answer your question from the comment "I was wondering  where you found the option name JAVA_COMMENT?" That is at the bottom of the *Live Template* dialog. You can set the context/scope for which the template (i.e. is shortcut) is applicable/available. Here's a screenshot.

[image: Live Template Diloag]

In case you are not aware, you can create the template by copying the XML I show and then pasting it into a template group. The paste option is available only if you have a valid template XML in your clipboard. Be sure there are no leading spaces or lines before the `<template` element. (I got the XML via the copy option.)

[image: Pasting a template]

Comment: That's really awesome! I was wondering where you found the option name JAVA_COMMENT?Are there any other option that can't be edited?

Comment: I've answered your comment question in the answer above.

Comment: Thanks,javau,that works.but there was a redundant Line.I just remove the last **&#10;    *** from the value of Template!